# Was Śrī Rāma elder or younger to Hanumāna?

Tags: rama, hanuman

Today (April 16th, 2022) coincides with the popularly celebrated Hanumāna Jayantī (Hanumān's birthday) i.e, on Caitra Pūrņimā.

Although, from [various sources](https://www.tv9hindi.com/spiritual/why-is-hanuman-jayanti-celebrated-twice-a-year-know-the-reason-and-real-date-1171452.html), I have found at least 8 different dates assigned to Hanumān's birthday, out of them two are the most popular, as follows:-

> **1. the full moon of the month of Chaitra (March/April; Caitra
> pūrņimā)**
>
> **2. the new moon of Karttik (Kārttik amāvasyā)**

<sup>[this book](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Shree_Hanuman_Leela/Jg4WDgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E2%80%8B&pg=PA30&printsec=frontcover), [this book](https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Hanuman/t10oDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%95%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B7%20%E0%A4%85%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%20%E0%A4%B9%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E2%80%8B&pg=PT32&printsec=frontcover), and several other, gives eight different birth-dates of Hanumāna</sup>

Date 1 is generally, the most popular, while Date 2 is observed by some people (for instance - the sadhus of the Hanumāna Garhi temple in Ayodhya, *so I have heard*)

In any case, the birth date (tithi) of Śrī Rāma has no ambiguity and is celebrated as Rāma navamī, the ninth of the bright fortnight (śukla-pakṣa) of the Chaitra month.

##### Question - Do the scriptures categorically mention who amongst Rāma & Hanumāna was born first?

Or can it be derived logically using scriptural evidence, who was [chronologically] elder amongst them?

Comment: http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/baala/sarga17/bala_17_frame.htm might  help..

Answer (score 2):

According to Hanuman Chalisa, Hanuman exists in all yugas

Wiki:

Devanagari

> चारों जुग परताप तुम्हारा।
> है परसिद्ध जगत उजियारा॥ २९ ॥

Hunterian

> chāro juga para tāpa tumhārā।
> hai parasiddha jagata ujiyyārā॥ 29 ॥

> Your glory is famous in all the four Yugas, and illuminates the whole world.[32][70][71]

> Rambharacharya adds that this verse refers to the Immortality and Glory of Lord Hanuman in all the four Yugas.

Rama is said to have been born in Treta Yuga.

That would make Hanuman older.

Comment: But as mentioned in the question, Hanuman also has a DOB. So this doesn't answer what I'm looking for.

Comment: if your question is "whose birthday (month,date) occurs earlier in the yearly calendar - then I'll withdraw the answer.  if your question who was born earlier, then my answer stands @vivikta